# PHP error function.imagejpeg

Tags: php

Basically, I have a problem with a script that I'm developing. The problem is that it wants to create a folder with 8bit text in it "ninety-ninenightsⅡ" the 2 at the end.

```
imagejpeg() [<a href='function.imagepng'>function.imagejpeg</a>]:
Unable to open 'cache/album/ninety-ninenightsⅡ/na.jpeg' for writing: 
No such file or directory in /home/****/public_html/card.php on line 113

<!-- language: lang-php -->
```

Comment: Where is the call to imagepng?

Comment: added more information // thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have troubles with the `Ⅱ` character who is UTF-8. The `str_*` php functions family are all latin1, so your character is being transformed to garbage.

Replace your code by :

```
$file = 'cache/album/' . mb_strtolower(preg_replace('|\s|u', '', $asdfgh['Title']), 'UTF-8') . '.jpg';
if (!file_exists($file))
{                              
    $gasd = imagecreatefromjpeg($asdfgh['Pictures']['Tile32px']);
```

Take care to use $file too on your `imagepng`.

You really should use logic variable names, when you'll come back in that code in some months/years, you'll be in real trouble.

Comment: its basically scraping information via json and then creating images with that information and thats what it asking me to create via erros.

Comment: The most simple and safe thing you may do is remove non alphanumeric / underscore chars from your file name. Isn't it?

Comment: maybe but ive tried to even replace using str_replace and that doesnt seem to work. just has a hard time creating this 1 folder lol

Comment: use preg_replace instead, as I said the `str_*` function family doesn't work with utf chars. That's very easy: `preg_replace("/" . preg_quote($to_find) . "/u", $replace_with, $subject);`

Comment: Thanks alot i just worked off your current code and added some extra 
`. mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','',`
i also added correct names :) thanks for the help +1 to your answer